# In what way the `TfidfVectorizer` deals with single-digit numbers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am bit confused about what exactly the `TfidfVectorizer` of `skelearn` does under the hood unbeknownst to me.

I have sentences such as this:

```
sentence_1 = 'Sum: 1 Mean: 1 Min:1'
```

But when I see the `vocabulary_` after the training I cannot find any element '1'.

I suspect that this is done for every single letter/number token by the `TfidfVectorizer`.

---

What is done by the `TfidfVectorizer` at this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the `token_pattern`, which is `’(?u)\b\w\w+\b’`. This means that it will extract alpha-numeric tokens with length greater than 1. Hence the tokens such as `1`, `2` are not getting figured out in the `vocubulary_`.

[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L260) place, where `token_pattern` is used to extract tokens.

To demonstrate an example,

```
import re
token_pattern = re.compile(r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b')
token_pattern.findall('i would like to test this 1 11')

# ['would', 'like', 'to', 'test', 'this', '11']
```

we can find that alpha-numeric tokens `i`, `1` were not getting extracted out of the `findall`, because of `\b\w\w+\b` pattern.

If single character tokens needs to be included, then use `\b\w+\b`.